# PHP file_put_contents create only empty file

Tags: php, file, file-put-contents

I have a problem with saving files on server (linux). On localhost (Windows) is function OK.

```
        umask(007);

        if (file_put_contents($path, (string) $data) === false) {
            log("error", "error create file");
        }
```

`$path` is OK, because file is created - but empty.

`$data` are PDF file ("%PDF-1.4...") or jpg file

`gettype($data)` returns "string"

Add string to this variable is OK too.

Thank you very much for your opinions.

Comment: How are you getting your `$data` value ?

Comment: It's from client - we uses xml rpc - do you think that this may cause problem? (because data looks right when I print them to error.log)

Comment: I would check $data before output. Maybe it is some object and converting to string returns empty string

Comment: check with adding string directly to $data variable.

Comment: @shibab No, it must be somewhere else, gettype($data) returns string and add string to this variable is OK too. I put "World" on the end